# how to load and display a bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I would like to display some sort of graphics on the screen. I know that I could use bitmap. I keep my image in folder `res/drawable-hdpi` and it is `player.png`.

Now I would like to load this image to my bitmap, how can I do this? Like this:

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/drawable-hdpi/player.png");
```

but it doesn't work. And I also would be grateful if somebody could tell me how to display this bitmap method on draw, like this:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas){    
  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, posX, posY, null);
}
```

Comment: Since you are referring to an asset that's built into the APK as a resource, you should use something like BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player).

Comment: Where is this `onDraw` in an `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have a simple sotution for you, but I don't if this what you want. Check my   code and let me know if works, please!

```
Drawable drawable = Context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image);
Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.player); 
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

The compilation process puts references to all of your resources in the R.java file.

EDIT: This code is done from a class that's inheriting from View.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aquery android library. it is quite easy to use. It is a opensource project. still in beta. But its quite stable, I am using it in all my applications.

aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");

http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI?tm=6